# Downside of using View Controller Containment

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I develop a lot of iOS apps and build quite complex user flows in terms of page management and such.

In many instances, the UINavigationController stack is great for pushing through a tree of possible pages, but lacks a lot of the customizability that I look for.

When that customizability is required, I end up using a lot of ViewController containment. It looks something like this:

```
//ParentViewController.m
@interface ParentViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) ChildViewController *childViewController;

@end

@implemenation ParentViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.childViewController = [[ChildViewController alloc]init];
    [self addChildViewController:self.childViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.childViewController.view];
    [self.childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Now of course this is a super simple example and it is many times much more complex with subclassed UIViews as the main view of the VC and a lot more logic, but I tend to do this sometimes even 5 or 10 times nested within different VCs.

So my question is: Is there any downside in terms of memory and utility in doing VC Containment (besides, of course, the added work of handling the stack manually, such as "Back" buttons)?

Comment: Your approach doesn't look to be efficient. Can you tell what you are trying to do and what type of customization you need in UINavigationController?

Comment: For instance, I have applications in which its necessary to animate certain views from one view controller to another (changing superview in the midst, many times using the UIWindow as the superview). The UINavigation stack makes this very difficult. And inefficient in what way? The amount of code? Or memory wise?

Comment: @AlexKoren I don't think there will be less difficulties of animating views using UIWindow from UINavigationController compared to your structure. Instead of asking about the downside of your current method, show me the problems you would like to overcome in another question. I could help and I am sure there must be a better way :)

Comment: There aren't any problems! I love the way that my apps come out and the way that they're structured. I'm just wondering why more people don't use View Controller containment like I do. Maybe there were management issues that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Can't you keep the navigation stack, but use custom transitions?

Answer (score 3):

I would say complexity and therefore maintainability are the main downsides of view controller containment. There are a number of subtleties you need to get right with view controller containment, or things can break in strange ways.

For more technical help on correct implementation of view controller containment, see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1

...in particular be sure to read the section entitled *Adding a Child View Controller to Your Content*

Comment: I was looking for a bit more of a technical answer, but I'll award you the bounty. If anyone has any info from a purely memory/performance standpoint, feel free to throw another answer down!

Comment: Updated my answer with my go-to reference for making sure I do view controller containment correctly. Be aware that it's quite possible to do an implementation that *appears to work* correctly, but then breaks in strange ways in certain obscure scenarios.